# How to get Firefox to open a Mac AppStore link directly into the App Store app

Tags: macos, firefox, hyperlink, mac-app-store

This is the link I'm trying to go to from my website's "Download on the Mac AppStore" button:
http://appstore.com/mac/gdollc/zing

This is the syntax Apple recommends at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1633/_index.html

When I try this link in Safari or Chrome, they handle it well, i.e. Safari will open the App Store app with the main page open at my app's page, and Chrome will do the same after prompting me if I want to open the App Store app.

But in Firefox, I get stuck on a page that shows "Connecting to the Mac App Store"
and a message saying "To use the Mac App Store, you need Mac OS 10.6.6 or greater. For more information, please click here." which isn't appropriate since I run Sierra.

That page is actually hosted by Apple as its URL is https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZContentLink.woa/wa/link?mt=11&path=mac%2fzing

Then a window appears with title "Launch application" with "This link needs to be opened with an application", and it offers me either iTunes (which is inappropriate for a macOS app in the Mac AppStore) or "Choose other Application".

Even if I click on this last option, the App Store app is grayed out, presumably because it thinks it can't handle the link.

Is there something I'm missing to get Firefox to behave like Safari & Chrome?
I disabled all NoScript/AdBlock software on Firefox for these tests. I'm running Firefox 55.0.3 (64-bit).
I've also tried this on another computer with the same behavior.